# Getting Exception when Adding a viewcontroller to SlideMenu

Tags: ios, objective-c

When trying to add a viewController to SlideMenu I am getting the following Exception

```
NSString *sss=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [d objectForKey:[row objectAtIndex:0]]]];


UIViewController *viewController = [[NSClassFromString(sss) alloc]initWithNibName:sss bundle:nil] ;
 [slideMenu addViewController:viewController withTitle:@"Manage Account(s)" andImage:nil];
```

**Error Message:**

incompatible pointer type sending `UIViewController` to parameter of type my other view controller

Comment: `UIViewController *viewController = [[NSClassFromString(sss) alloc]initWithNibName:sss bundle:nil] ;` problem in this line. try this `NSClassFromString(sss) *viewController = [[NSClassFromString(sss) alloc]initWithNibName:sss bundle:nil] ;` or `sss *viewController = [[NSClassFromString(sss) alloc]initWithNibName:sss bundle:nil] ;`

Comment: i think it expecting a view controller of type MyOtherViewController but you are giving of type UIViewController...